# magento - hackers or exploit

Tags: magento, xss, exploit

I found these entries in magento log file. Not sure if this is hackers attempting to enter enter bad data, or evidence of an exploit. From log file:

```
var/log/exception.log:4118:2014-10-30T22:46:39+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: No date part in '<?import namespace="CrossSiteScripting" implementation="http://ha.ckers.org/CrossSiteScripting.htc">' found.
var/log/exception.log:4131:exception 'Zend_Locale_Exception' with message 'No date part in '<?import namespace="CrossSiteScripting" implementation="http://ha.ckers.org/CrossSiteScripting.htc">' found.' in lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php:869
var/log/exception.log:4352:2014-10-30T22:46:49+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: No date part in '<SCRIPT SRC=http://ha.ckers.org/xss.js></SCRIPT>' found.
var/log/exception.log:4365:exception 'Zend_Locale_Exception' with message 'No date part in '<SCRIPT SRC=http://ha.ckers.org/xss.js></SCRIPT>' found.' in lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php:869
var/log/exception.log:4534:2014-10-30T22:46:55+00:00 DEBUG (7): Exception message: No date part in '<SCRIPT/XSS SRC="http://ha.ckers.org/xss.js"></SCRIPT>' found.
var/log/exception.log:4547:exception 'Zend_Locale_Exception' with message 'No date part in '<SCRIPT/XSS SRC="http://ha.ckers.org/xss.js"></SCRIPT>' found.' in lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php:869
```

They appear to be coming from function in lib/Zend/Locale/Format.php - line 869

```
private static function _parseDate($date, $options)
```

relevant code is:

```
// split number parts
$split = false;
preg_match_all('/\d+/u', $number, $splitted);

if (count($splitted[0]) == 0) {
    iconv_set_encoding('internal_encoding', $oenc);
    #require_once 'Zend/Locale/Exception.php';
    throw new Zend_Locale_Exception("No date part in '$date' found.");
}
if (count($splitted[0]) == 1) {
    $split = 0;
}
$cnt = 0;
foreach($parse as $key => $value) {
```

Answer (score 1):

The log file entries shows evidence of someone attempting to identify a [cross site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) vulnerability. Based on the code snippet you provided it is not vulnerable.